# Get subject, body and attachment info from Compose UI in gmail addon

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-addons

I have this gmail addon which has a `composeTrigger` defined in `appscript.json` like this.

```
    "composeTrigger": {
      "selectActions": [
        {
          "text": "ComposeTrigger",
          "runFunction": "composeTrigger"
        }
      ],
      "draftAccess": "METADATA"
    },
```

In `Main.js` (or any other file) I have defined `composeTrigger` as:

```
function composeTrigger(event) {
    Logger.info(event.draftMetadata)
}
```

Now this `draftMetadata` only contains details of recipients (to, cc, bcc).

I want to access the subject, body and attachments also, but I have been unable to do so.

It's easy to access them when a mail is opened, from `event.messsageMetadata`, but `event.messageMetadata` is not available on the compose trigger  callback.

Comment: Ever figure out why they don't give us this? Makes no sense. I can get the exact  messageId I need when using the `contextualTriggers.onTriggerFunction`. So annoying  :-/

Comment: Filed an issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/176416923